# Sometime pathos.multiprocessing.Pool can't be terminated correctly

Tags: python, centos, pool, terminate

I try to use pathos.multiprocessing.Pool in my project.
However, it will meet the following problem when I terminate the Pool.
I use CentOS 6.5, I'm not sure if it is caused by pathos.multiprocessing.Pool or other thing, can anyone help me on it?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1073, in run
  self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "receiver.py", line 132, in kill_clients
  pool.terminate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 465, in terminate
  self._terminate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/util.py", line 207, in __call__
  res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 513, in _terminate_pool
  p.terminate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 137, in terminate
  self._popen.terminate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/forking.py", line 174, in terminate
  os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

OSError: [Errno 3] No such process

The wired thing is that at the beginning, it works well. But when the 4th job is received, there will be such problem.

```
    class Receiver:
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        self.results={}
    def kill_clients(self, client_list, pool):
        for client in client_list:
            client.kill()
        pool.terminate()
    def process_result(self, result):
        if result is None:
            self.results = {}
            return
        res = result.split(':')
        if len(res) != 4:
            raise Exception("result with wrong format: %s" % result)
        self.results['%s_%s' % (res[0], res[1])] = {"code": res[3], "msg": res[4]}
    ...

     def handler(self, job):
        self.lg.debug("Receive job in rtmp_start_handler.")
        self.lg.debug("<%s>" % str(job))
        # each client corresponding one process
        cli_counts = job['count']
        pool = Pool(processes=cli_counts)
        clients = []
        try:
            for i in xrange(cli_counts):
                rtmp_cli = RtmpClient(job['case'], i)
                clients.append(rtmp_cli)
            [pool.apply_async(client.run, callback=self.process_result)
             for client in clients]
            pool.close()
            sleep(1)
            self.lg.debug("All clients are started.")
            t = Timer(
                job['timeout'],
                self.kill_clients,
                args=(clients, pool)
            )
            t.start()
            self.lg.debug("Timer is started. timeout %s s" % job['timeout'])
            pool.join()
        except Exception, e:
            self.lg.warning("Exception occurred: %s" % e)
            self.lg.warning(format_exc())
            return "0"

        # here the self.results shall be ready
        return self.parse_results()
```

Answer (score 0):

The OSError is not caused by the Pool but by my program issue.
When I use Popen to create a subprocess and exec ffmpeg, it will exit immediately(due to other problem), so when I try to kill the subprocess, it it not existed by then. That's why OSError will be raised.